# Web Method doesn't execute my PL/SQL procedure

Tags: java, web-services, plsql, webmethod

My update_password PL/SQL procedure seems to never be executed in the web method. I've checked using 'ERROR1' and 'ERROR2'. mResult is always set to 'ERROR1'. Can you spot anything unusual about my execute? Or maybe there's something wrong with it I can't see. I've spent too much time on this already...

```
@WebMethod
public String updatePassword(@WebParam(name = "mEmail")
    String mEmail, @WebParam(name = "mPassword")
    String mPassword, @WebParam(name = "mNewPassword")
    String mNewPassword, @WebParam(name = "mConfirmPassword")
    String mConfirmNewPassword) {
    ClsConnectionData conn = null;
    ResultSet rst;
    String mResult = "ERROR1";
    try
    {
        conn = new ClsConnectionData();
        rst = conn.execute("ULM_SIM_PACKAGE.update_password('" + mEmail + "','" + mPassword + "','" + mNewPassword + "','" + mConfirmNewPassword + "',:1)");
        if (rst.next())
            mResult =  rst.getString(1);
        else
            mResult = "ERROR2";
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    return mResult;
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting to be returned by your update_password procedure?

Comment: listcursor. a listcursor is of type refcur: 'type refcur_type is ref cursor;' Final reply should equal to 'OK' as I have this in my update_password procedure: open listcursor for
            select 'OK' procedureResult from Dual;

Comment: i think that it is likely that this procedure is not responding in the way you are expecting hence rst.next() is always returning false

Comment: I understand, however shouldn't mResult = "ERROR2" in that case as the first if fails and goes to the else?

Comment: sorry, yes you are right, I suspect the execute method is throwing an exception, you should be able to debug this or see the exception stack trace

Comment: I have catch exception and printStackTrace function in there however I do not know where to look for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161740/discussion-between-hellomate-and-pillhead).

Comment: i'm sorry I can't access the chat but in general you need to debug your application in an IDE to determine its behaviour

Comment: I've tried debugging but not sure how to proceed with that. I've never debugged anything like that.

Comment: as a first pass just step over each line of code in the method you have provided and see what happens.  If you get an exception you can use the stack trace to give you a clue as to the problem.  If not you'll need to dig further

Comment: The thing is step over is 'grey'/unavailable. I can only pause and resume.

Comment: I have managed to get to the stack trace by right clicking java file and selecting Test Web Service. During debugging phase it would print the stack trace. Finally! It's a nullPointerException. rst is null but I'm still not sure how to execute update_password properly to get an expected outcome.

Comment: please add the stacktrace to the question

Comment: I've found the solution. Posted that in the answers. Phew...

Answer (score 0):

Found what the actual bug is. I've been missing a call to a function that defines the connection.

There is a connectDefault() function that should be called under `conn = new ClsConnectionData();` like so:

```
conn = new ClsConnectionData();
conn.connectDefault();
```

update_password couldn't be executed as there was no database connection...

Comment: hooray!  congratulations.